# How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value) in DQL?

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I can not get this query in a symfony2 project that I have.

**My Table:**

```
id  course  datetime    numOrden   
---|-----|------------|--------
1  | 1º  | 04/11/2016 | 1   
2  | 2º  | 04/11/2016 | 2
5  | 3º  | 04/11/2016 | 5  
3  | 4º  | 03/11/2016 | 4   
4  | 5º  | 03/11/2016 | 3
```

I need to get the course whose value in the "numOrden" column is the maximum( in this case it would be the 3rd course). For this I have used the following query in Doctrine2:

```
public function findCourse()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT c FROM BackendBundle:Curso c WHERE c.numOrden in (SELECT max(c.numOrden) FROM BackendBundle:Curso )')
    ->getResult();
}
```

Or

```
    public function findCourse()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT c FROM Bundle:Course c WHERE c.numOrden=(SELECT max(c.numOrden) FROM Bundle:Course )')
    ->getResult();
}
```

But it shows the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got end of string. (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using another alias in the subselect as:

```
    public function findCourse()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT c FROM Bundle:Course c WHERE c.numOrden=(SELECT max(co.numOrden) FROM Bundle:Course co )')
    ->getResult();
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: That was the problem. I tried the same alias previously, but I did not try another one. Thank you!!