# How to get the latest record in each group using GROUP BY in DQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can not get this query in a symfony2 project that I have.

**My Table: Case_file**

```
id  id_student  last_course  Academic_year  
---|----------|------------|--------------
1  |    1     | 1º Primary |  2014 / 2015   
2  |    2     | 2º Primary |  2014 / 2015
5  |    3     | 1º Primary |  2014 / 2015  
3  |    1     | 2º Primary |  2015 / 2016    
4  |    2     | 3º Primary |  2015 / 2016
```

I need to obtain for each student the last record that I have according to the academic year.

With the following query I obtain the first row that is found of each student:

```
public function findOldEstudent()
{

return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT c FROM BackendBundle:case_file c INNER JOIN c.student s  WHERE s.active=0 GROUP BY s.id   ')
    ->getResult();
}
```

Whose solution I show in the following table:

```
id  id_student  last_course  Academic_year  
---|----------|------------|--------------
1  |    1     | 1º Primary |  2014 / 2015   *
2  |    2     | 2º Primary |  2014 / 2015   *
3  |    3     | 1º Primary |  2014 / 2015
```

And what I want is to get the last row according to the academic year, as shown in the following table:

```
id  id_student  last_course  Academic_year  
---|----------|------------|--------------
1  |    1     | 2º Primary |  2015 / 2016    *
2  |    2     | 3º Primary |  2015 / 2016    *
3  |    3     | 1º Primary |  2014 / 2015
```

For this I have tried to sort the rows with ORDER BY in the following query, but it continues to return the first row found:

```
public function findOldEstudent()
{

return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT c FROM BackendBundle:case_file c INNER JOIN c.student s  WHERE s.active=0 GROUP BY s.id ORDER BY c.academic_year DESC')
    ->getResult();
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The order by sorts after everything is selected, not the other way around as you want to.

Comment: Thank @Linkan, I understand, but would you know how to get to that solution? I need to be able to search in descending order until I find the first row of each student, which would be the last row recorded in that case.

Comment: The way to go is SELECT id_student,MAX(Academic_year) AS Academic_year FROM tablename GROUP BY id_student After that join last course on id_student and academic year.

Comment: I was trying right now, but I can not get it to work. Something will be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with the following query:

```
public function findOldEstudent()
{

 return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    'SELECT c FROM BackendBundle:case_file c INNER JOIN c.student s  WHERE c.academic_year IN (select MAX(ca.academic_year) FROM BackendBundle:case_file ca INNER JOIN ca.student st GROUP BY st.id) and s.active=0')
    ->getResult();
 }
```

The problem I had is that I used the same alias in the subselect, as it happened in another similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678668/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-in-dql) and I did not remember.

Hope that helps.